# Actionscript 3 - Play Sound Parallel and Very Often

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I have a sound that must be played really often and the playback will overlap the playing of the same sound.

I kept my sounds really short but I can still hear the lack of plays. Does that mean when I try to parallel-play a sound 1000 times it will play it only 8 and ignore the others ? How many channels are there ?

**Can I control and modify the parallel play behavior ?**

Answer (score 1):

AS3 maxes out at 32 channels. Make sure that once you're done playing a sound, you're disposing of its sound channel so that it can be freed up for another `Sound` to use it.

Comment: interesting, btw does this rule apply to adobe air? and can this be changed some how that you may know of? thanks

Comment: Yes, this rule also applies to AIR. I don't know of a way to change it, and I'm not sure you'd want to as I can't imagine a situation in which you'd want to layer more than 32 sounds on top of each other. Sorry I don't have a better answer.

Comment: the reason i ask imagine a music sequencer, you would be limited to 32 tracks thats all